# Change online database values using VB .net

Tags: vb.net

I wonder if it is possible to make changes on online database server. this is my code but it really doesn't work it just returns the same values. The goal is to change data with datagridview but since I couldn't do it I tried just change one name. I'm sorry for this primitive code, I'm only a beginner.

```
     Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    mysqlconnection = New MySqlConnection
    mysqlconnection.ConnectionString = "server=db4free.net;port=xxxx; user id=xxxxx; password=xxxxxxx; database=progdata"
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand
    Dim myadapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    'Dim dbdataset As New DataTable()
    'Dim dbsource As New BindingSource
    Dim DataSet1 As New DataSet()

    Dim query As String = "select * from Products"
    command = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconnection)
    ' myadapter.SelectCommand = command
    myadapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(command)
    mysqlconnection.Open()

    Dim builder As MySqlCommandBuilder = New MySqlCommandBuilder(myadapter)
    myadapter.Fill(DataSet1, "Products")
    DataGridView4.DataSource = DataSet1.Tables("Products").DefaultView
    mysqlconnection.Close()
    mysqlconnection = Nothing

    myadapter.Update(DataSet1.Tables("Products"))
    DataSet1.AcceptChanges()
  End Sub
```

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

> AcceptChanges does not save data back to the database - to do that,
>   you need to call the update method on your tableadapter/dataadapter.
>   Datasets are 'rollbackable'. All the changes you make can be reversed
>   by calling RejectChanges, (whereupon any Added rows will be removed,
>   and rows marked Modified or Deleted will be returned to how they
>   were); or committed by calling AceptChanges, whereupon the new data
>   becomes the current data. The data is still only in the dataset at
>   this point though - until you call Update.